# Nav-bar changes size when I click on anther page

Tags: html, css

Different size on nav-bar on different pages. On the "index.html" the nav bar is 222x100 and it looks way smaller and on the other page "faq.html" it is 1110x100 and it´s not even half as big as the navbar in index.html. How to make the navbar the same size in every site?

Here are the files:

https://github.com/wreckitralph-tech/html-css-help.git

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your repository, tested it (I had to copy the css and the image into their folders, like `/src/img` and `/src/css` ), and it gave me the same navbar on all the pages.

The text was very small, so in the css i replaced the `3px` tag with a `20px` so I could see clearer the text. The final result was working, and I could switch to all the htmls as intended.

Here is a picture of what i got:
[Navbar-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKVdF.png)

So, in conclusion, you may have removed the line that was causing the issue for this question, or your browser cached the css file on only one webpage. For this, you can clean your browser's cache ( some of them have a specific command, or it can be found on the settings ).